# Google Calendar insert event : JSON parse error through @RequestBody Spring

Tags: java, google-calendar-api

I try to insert an event to Google Calendar.

If I create my event with Java Object directly, using the [Java client](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#examples), I have no problem.

**My problem is when I send my event in JSON to my controller: (The Content-type is application/json, and I use postman or command line to send it)**

**My JSON:**

```
{
  "summary": "Google I/O 2015",
  "location": "800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103",
  "description": "A chance to hear more about Google\"s developer products.",
  "start":{
    "dateTime":"2018-04-07T17:00:00.000-04:00"
  },
  "end":{
    "dateTime":"2018-04-07T18:00:00.000-04:00"
  },
  "attendees": [
    {"email": "lpage@example.com"},
    {"email": "sbrin@example.com"}
  ]
}
```

**My controller:**

```
@PostMapping(path = "/new/event/{calendarId}/{sendNotification}")
public ResponseEntity<?> newEvent(@NonNull @PathVariable String calendarId, 
    @NonNull @PathVariable boolean sendNotification,
    @NonNull @RequestBody Event event) {

  Event eventCreated = postEventService.postNewEvent(calendarId, sendNotification, event);

  return new ResponseEntity<>(eventCreated, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

**And here is my error:**

```
{
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "message": "JSON parse error: Can not set com.google.api.services.calendar.model.EventDateTime field com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Event.start to java.util.LinkedHashMap; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not set com.google.api.services.calendar.model.EventDateTime field com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Event.start to java.util.LinkedHashMap (through reference chain: com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Event[\"start\"])",
  "path": "/new/event/primary/true"
}
```

My problem is that the exact same JSON works perfectly on the [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#try-it) in the documentation.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: wild guess are you seeting the content type?   Not exactly sure what language it is you are sending this post in.

Comment: Yes sorry missing those information, I will add them. My Content-type is application/json (if I do not send this, I have a 415 UnsupportedMediaType). To send this post, I use postman or in command line.

Comment: @RomainBarbier, Have you managed to know the answer? I'm facing the same problem?

Comment: @user3580691 nope sorry... It is an old project and since I did not managed with this solution I used a custom parser or something like that... (So old that I do not remember how I did sorry...)

Comment: Would you please past **Event** and corresponding child object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve this error by creating a custom JSON deserializer. In Spring Boot you can do that using @JsonComponent annotation.

Comment: Yes if I remember well it was something like that that I used